# Core Data Programming Guide: intermediate join entity example, MUTUAL or NOT?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In the example of using **"[intermediate join entity](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10)"**

To find out who one person’s friends are, you have to aggregate all the friend destinations of the friends relationship, for example:

```
NSSet *personsFriends = [aPerson valueForKeyPath:@"friends.friend"];
```

Is above line of code getting a given person's MUTUAL friends? or just ONE-WAY friends, which means only getting "peoples who are treated by this given person as his friends"?

I am not certain, because **"To find out who one person’s friends are"** sounds like ONE-WAY friendship (that could be why there is a strange relationship **befriendedBy represents those who count the source as their friend. FriendInfo represents information about one friendship, “in one direction.” .**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really confusing example. There are two possibilities.

1. In most cases being "friends" is a mutual thing. In this case you would have a self-referencing  many-to-many relationship of a `Person`, perhaps called `friends`. The relationship would be mutual.
2. You seem to be implying that it is possible to add another person as a friend even if that person is does not reciprocate. In order to lift the confusion give this many-to-many relationship another distinct name, e.g. `contacts`. This would be the `Person`s that have been added unilaterally. In Core Data, all relationships are best modelled as mutual, so you can use another relationship `potentialFriends` that is the inverse relationship of `contacts`.  Maybe there are better names, but you get the idea.

The intermediate join entity is only necessary if you want to store additional attribute with a particular relationship, e.g. the date a contact request was made. In this case, you would have the join entity e.g.  `friendLink`, which would  have a to-one relationship to two distinct `Person`s. You can model the state of the link (unilateral or mutual) in this entity.

Comment: How can my comments stay here? Mine always disappear after a while...a stack overflow bug?

Comment: Mundi: thanks a lot for your answer!!! From my modified question, you can see Apple-Doc did try to use 2 to-many relationships to replace reflexive relationship (applied on earlier "cousin" example), meanwhile stated the relationship as unilateral. Your #2 option is right on target, better yet, applying Twitter's <followed> + <following> can be another attractive alternative. Cheers!